# Scraping a website by scrolling and copy-pasting content

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping

I'm scraping a website for which I can only copy and paste its content into Excel. To my knowledge, Python, R, or other languages do not work.

My method right now is to copy and paste the content of its website. I copy as I scroll down and the website loads up the content. It works, but only for small quantities. However, if I keep scrolling for several minutes and attempt to copy and paste the content into Excel, then not all content appears to pop up in Excel.

I'm using Google Chrome as my browser.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to scrap a website contents without any javascript requirement.
You may want JSoup library using Java - here's a quick [link](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/jsoup-html-parsing-library.html) for your reference.